# Does push_back cause refrence invalidation in 2d vectors?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a 2d vector of ints and I `push_back` a bunch of objects into one of the middle internal vectors. Do I risk iterator/reference invalidation?

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> ints2d;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
     ints2d.push_back(std::vector<int>());
     ints2d[i].resize(10,0);
}

//later during some runtime event

for (int i = 0, i < 100; ++i)
{
    ints2d[3].push_back(8);
}

//are my references at risk of being invalid now?
```

Comment: Iterators not, but references to `ints2d[3]` may be invalidated

Comment: @user3365922 both.

Comment: @NathanOliver, God that kind of massive overly broad question is a bad dupe target.

Comment: @SergeyA yep, I was wrong https://stackoverflow.com/a/54004916/3365922

Answer (score 3):

You have (potentially) invalidated references to the vector you are pushing to (the one at the index 3 of `ints2d`). All other references remain valid.

Comment: So the outer vector will wont be moved in memory because the ints2d[3] changed in size?

Comment: @user2234811 They won't be moved.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is easily answered by reading [a bit of documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back). Basically, as mentioned in the previous link, "If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.".

Of course only references/iterators into the vector you are actually doing `push_back` on are potentially invalidated. The containing container is *not* affected.

Comment: Only the size of the vector that was pushed to changed.

Comment: So this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @ruohola Yes it does. The question was "Lets say I have a 2d vector of ints and I push_back a bunch of objects into one of the middle internal vectors do I risk iterator/reference invalidation." - And yes you do, for the vector pushed into. Which should be clear by the documentation I linked and quoted. Of course there's no invalidation of the *containing* vector, but that's not what's being modified, so that should be obvious.

Comment: It's *very* obvious that the question is exactly about invalidating iterators to the vectors or the containing vector.

Comment: @ruohola Maybe obvious to you. Not obvious to me. But regardless, I think the answer I provided answers the question. You may disagree - which is  fine, that's what votes are for.